# How can I split a Dataset from a .csv file for Training and Testing?

Tags: python, csv, split, data-science

I'm using Python and I need to split my .csv imported data in two parts, a training and test set, E.G 70% training and 30% test.

I keep getting various errors, such as `'list' object is not callable` and so on.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Thanks

EDIT:

The code is basic, I'm just looking to split the dataset.

```
from csv import reader
with open('C:/Dataset.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = list(reader(f)) #Imports the CSV
    data[0:1] ( data )
```

`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, but without seeing your code it's hard to help in particular.

Comment: please post the code and the complete error.

Comment: Added the code to the post.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Dataset.csv')
df['split'] = np.random.randn(df.shape[0], 1)

msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) <= 0.7

train = df[msk]
test = df[~msk]
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!

Comment: worked perfect but can you tell how to write this train and test data in .csv file...??

Comment: @DeepakChawla `train.to_csv('train.csv', index=False)` and the same with test.

Comment: Output file is not having the exact percentage?
If my dataset is of size 100, then its not returning 70 rows.
Every time it is returning different number of rows but not 70.

Answer (score 10):

Better practice and maybe more random is to use `df.sample`:

```
from numpy.random import RandomState
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Dataset.csv')
rng = RandomState()

train = df.sample(frac=0.7, random_state=rng)
test = df.loc[~df.index.isin(train.index)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `read_csv ()` function from the pandas module. It reads all your data straight into the dataframe which you can use further to break your data into train and test. Equally, you can use the [`train_test_split()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function from the scikit-learn module.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` as its **the best for purpose of splitting a dataset** below i'm giving code to use it

`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Dataset.csv')
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data["qus"], 
data["ans"],test_size = 0.3)

train_data = pd.concat([x_train , y_train], axis = 1)
test_data = pd.concat([x_train , y_train], axis = 1)
train_data.head()
```

`

Assuming that your csv contains 2 columns one for question and other for answer